# wordpress: click on Parentpage Redirect on first child page programmatically

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to redirect users on first child page.

for example there is parent page:   Page A it has 2 child pages:   child1 and child 2

when user click on Page A that redirects user to child 1 page

there are too many redirection plugins  to redirect parent to  child 1 that is manully set. I want this dynamically

is it possible to redirect the parent page on first child page programmatically?

Answer (score 7):

The following worked like a charm. (http://www.wprecipes.com/wordpress-page-template-to-redirect-to-first-child-page)

To achieve this recipe, you have to create a page template. Create a new file and paste the following code in it:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Redirect To First Child
*/
if (have_posts()) {
  while (have_posts()) {
    the_post();
    $pagekids = get_pages("child_of=".$post->ID."&sort_column=menu_order");
    $firstchild = $pagekids[0];
    wp_redirect(get_permalink($firstchild->ID));
    exit;
  }
}
?>
```

Save the file under the name redirect.php and upload it to the wp-content/themes/your-theme directory of your WordPress install. Once done, you can use the page template.

Answer (score 4):

Try below code for the same :

```
$pageChilds = get_pages("child_of=".$post->ID."&sort_column=menu_order");
if ($pageChilds) {
$firstchild = $pageChilds[0];
wp_redirect(get_permalink($firstchild->ID));
}
```

Let me know if you have any queries!

Thanks.

Comment: Where is you parent page link is situated? if in top navigation menu then in header.php file or else.

Comment: for menu i have list the only parent pages. there isn't any other way to redirect user to first child page. because the code you have given is not working .. i think it only works in loops. if you have answered through http://wordpress.org/support/topic/redirect-parent-page-to-first-child-page  which is not working anymore. i tried it before posting here

Comment: Better add `exit;` after `wp_redirect()`, as the [reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect) says: "wp_redirect() does not exit automatically and should almost always be followed by exit"

Answer (score 2):

In cases like this I just add a link to the menu, and change the url to "parent/child"[image]

Comment: This is not a solution, when the user manually goes to /parent :)