# Need direction on a seemingly complex menu walker for automatically inserting a parent link li in it's submenu ul

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I'd appreciate some direction on how to accomplish something with my WordPress menu. I've Googled this for hours without avail. I was to automatically insert a parent link into it's immediate submenu ul. For example, normal output is this:

Parent Menu Item 1
Parent Menu Item 2
--Submenu Item 1
--Submenu Item 2
Parent Menu Item 3

I'm looking for this:

Parent Menu Item 1
Parent Menu Item 2
--Parent Menu Item 2
--Submenu Item 1
--Submenu Item 2
Parent Menu Item 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `wp_nav_menu()` has a setting for this. Rewriting the entire menu rendering function would likely be very arduous.

One workaround would be to have "Parent Menu Item 2" as an actual first child page underneath the parent page of "Parent Menu Item 2", and use the code in this SO question:

[wordpress: click on Parentpage Redirect on first child page programmaticaly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19113582)

to automatically redirect to it. That would, however, change the behaviour on all pages: if you open a page that has children, you will always be automatically redirected to the first child.

Comment: Thanks much for your help. I guess there's a reason a Google search has turned up virtually nothing regarding this :)